UserForm that saves values of the fields to row "Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed"
I have a UserForm with text fields that saves the values of the fields to a new row in a worksheet upon clicking the Save button on the form.
Today the previously working form is throwing an error.

When I click "Debug" it takes me to:

When I hover over the statement, it has correctly captured the value of the field.

Corruption is possible. Do a cold reboot and check if the issue persists.

If someone would like to take a look at the entire workbook and Visual Basic code then I would be super open to sending it to you.  I can do that. Feel free to upload it to dropbox or free file sharing site and share the link here. Ensure that the file doesn't contain any confidential stuff.

@SiddharthRout - That would be amazing. Try to download it here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iHPTjjMnytuVOxqVT1lpDvnJEBTGJIxx/view?usp=sharing. Start the macro and the issue occurs when you click the "New" button and try to save a new event.

I don't understand why it would randomly start throwing this error after working. Does anyone have ideas? Did you get the error after converting the range to table in Hiring Events Listing? ;)

You have converted your range to a table and you are trying to add data to that table. You have 2 options.

Change the table back to range.
If you want to keep the table, then add a new row using ListRows.Add first and then add the values.

Is this what you are trying?
Private Sub WriteDataToSheet()
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim status As String
    
    status = GetFeaturedStatus
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hiring Events Listing")
    
    Dim Tbl As ListObject
    Set Tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table3")
    
    With ws
        newRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        
        Tbl.ListRows.Add Position:=newRow
    
        .Cells(newRow, 1).Value = txtEventName.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 2).Value = txtEventDate.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 3).Value = txtLocationNme.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 4).Value = txtStreetAddress.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 5).Value = txtCity.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 6).Value = txtState.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 7).Value = txtZip.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 8).Value = txtStart.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 9).Value = txtEnd.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 10).Value = txtPositionsHiring.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 11).Value = txtLocationsHiring.Value
        .Cells(newRow, 12).Value = status
    End With
End Sub

You may want to see Working with Tables in Microsoft Excel VBA
